# EJB3.0 - Transaction Rollback - Multiple Nested Methods

Tags: java, transactions, javabeans, ejb-3.0

Below is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
@Stateless(name = "TestBean", mappedName = "TestBean")
@Local
public class TestBean
{
  @Resource
  SessionContext ctx;

  @EJB
  TestBean2 testBean2;

  public TestBean()
  {
  }

  public void doSomething()
  {
    testBean2.methodA();
    boolean isSuccess = testBean2.methodB();
    if(!isSuccess)
     ctx.setRollbackOnly();
  }  
}
```

The configuration of 'TestBean2' is identical to 'TestBean'.

The problem with the above is that when methodB in testBean2 fails, the changes done in methodA are not being rollbacked/reverted. The change done in methodA are through the persist method in EntityManager.

Now, I know i haven't specified any transaction attributes but I've read the that default transaction attribute is usually REQUIRED.

One final note, i know there are lot of threads related to these issues but i've been going thought them and there are tons of them.So if there's a thread out there similar to the case above then i'd appreciate if you'd guide me to it.

Thanks

UPDATE:

In methodA, I'm issuing a flush statement after i do persist (Using EntityManager). After removing the flush statement, the rollback worked as expected. My datasource configuraiton is all done on the weblogic server where the 'Support Global Transaction' flag is checked.

Obviously the flush method should not issue a commit statement. So why is it actually committing?

Comment: Could you try to outcomment the setRollbackOnly() code and instead of returning false throw an exception in methodB()? The exception would be wrapped by an EJBException an the container will automatically manage the rollback.

Comment: By the way the default transaction attribute is the correct one for your use case. Required means that if an transaction is already started during the method invocation it will be executed in it's context and if no transaction already exists a new one will be startend. Requires_New always starts a new transaction. Mandatory annotated methods will throw an exception if the method will be executed without an already existing transaction. Supported takes an existing transaction if such one already exists and Not_Supported methods doesn't use any transactions.

Comment: are you sure that your bean execute in a transactional context? please post the datasource configuration

Comment: @ptk93 I tried throwing an exception but nothing happened. I'm sure that im running in a transactional because in other methods im able to rollback when the entire logic is inside the method itself and not residing in other beans/methods

Comment: I've added an UPDATE to the question to help narrow down the problem

Comment: JPA entities are stored in the persistence context that acts as a cache in front of your database. By default the persistence provider automatically performs the synchronization between the modified entities stored in the persistence context and the data store. The synchronization may happen after each successful transaction (can be overridden by using setFlushMode). flush() is a function to explicitly force the synchronization of the entity state with the database, but this doesn't mean a commit will be performed.

Comment: If a special isolation mode is set, the changes in the database could be seen before the transaction was finished. How have you tested the wrong behavior? By the way have you specified JTA as transaction type in your persistence.xml?